# Remove Duplicate JSON data objects IOS7

Tags: ios, json, post

Hi in my application I'm passing the `sqlite3` database data to my online server using `JSON` post method in that when i print the `JSON` data each record give two duplicate record for example i have record with name xxx means the same record in `JSON` its showing three time please tell me how to remove that duplicate records.

```
 [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field1Str] forKey:@"name"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field2Str] forKey:@"phone"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field3Str] forKey:@"city"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field4Str] forKey:@"email"];

        [array addObject:_dataDictionary];


        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        NSURL *someURLSetBefore =[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];
        [request setURL:someURLSetBefore];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        // print json:
        NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
```

If print the  array where i have stored the data into data dictionary there its showing correctly but in json only its taking duplicate records please tell me how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Option parameter

```
options:kNilOptions
```

to

```
options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
```

in this line

```
 NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Comment: after changing into NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted its not converting into json data

Comment: NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; its nsmutablearray